# Converting a string of characters to a string of 1s and 0s that represent those characters

Tags: c++, character-encoding, type-conversion

I want to convert a string of characters (obviously each one byte) into a string of 1s and 0s that represent the binary code for each character with the least significant bit first.

For example the string "Ab3" would become "10000010" for 'A' concatenated with "01000110" for 'b' concatenated with "11001100" for '3'. Notice how all of the characters are exactly 8 bits, i think this is the case because characters need to have all 8 bits to be saved correctly. If this is true then the whole string for this example should be "100000100100011011001100"

I  can't think of how to do this with the bitshift operators because you can't cast each bit into a char, but I know there must be a way to do it.

NOTE: I am not allowed to use bitset (or any STL) for this project.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question is how to convert a byte to a binary string representation

Comment: +1 for the answers that use STL, and -1 for the question with the fake limitations

Comment: yes, but need to do this without using bitset or any STL library.

edit: What do you mean "fake limitations"? This is a project for a data structures class and the professor said explicitly we may not use any STL library except <string>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::bitset`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    std::string bits;
    std::string s = "abcd";

    for (std::string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
        std::bitset<CHAR_BIT> bset;
            bset |= (unsigned char)*it;
            bits += bset.to_string();
    }

    std::cout << bits << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** the relevant part re-written according to stupid limitations:

```
std::string bits;
std::string s = "abcd";

for (std::string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
    unsigned char c = *it;

    for (int i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        bits += '0' + ((c >> i) & 1);
}

std::cout << bits << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am not allowed to use bitset for this project.

Comment: @user0123 Don't you think it would have been worth mentioning that you can't use a standard library class!!!???

Comment: yeah i'm sorry, i added that to the post.

Comment: Haha, once again i apologize. I forgot that most people don't have the ridiculous limitations that I have on this project.

Comment: @user0123 Yeah... I will also write an answer without `bitset`. In the meantime, grab a good tutorial on the binary number system and bitwise operations (and their corresponding operators in C++).

Comment: -Thanks a ton for the help. I have been google as we speak, it's just the conversion to string that has been tripping me up.

Comment: @user0123 Well, you can concatenate characters to `std::string` using the `+=` operator, have you read the documentation for `std::string`?

Comment: I know i can concatenate characters to strings. I am confuse on how a string would take in the bit as a character. Also how do i ensure that it is being ordered LSB first? How do i know how my computer (or other computers) store their characters LSB or MSB first?

Comment: @user0123 You change `for (int i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i--)` to `for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)`... But **please** think about it... just a bit... it **really** is **trivial.** (Especially since I've shown you a complete, compilable solution.)

Comment: I think what that does is start at i=8 (assuming an 8 bit unsigned char) grabs that bit and concatenates it to bits and then iterates down so now it looks at the 6th bit, etc etc down to the 0th bit which should be the MSB. 

Can you explain how you are allowed to add '0' to (c>>i)&1? I dont quite understand. Are you defaulting to adding a zero unless you and a certain bit of the byte with 1 and it comes out true?

Comment: @user0123 Huh? Bit 0 is the LSB. Bit 7 is the MSB. I think you need to revise some lessons about the binary system... And how are we allowed to add `'0'`? Well, `'0'` is a `char`, so it's an integral type (it's the character code of the character `0`). Again, you seem to be in the **very serious** need of learning basic C++ concepts and language features. I can't teach you C++ in one Stack Overflow-answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
stringstream ss; 

for(char c: std::string("Ab3")) 
     ss << std::bitset<8>(c);  

cout << ss.str();
```

Comment: How did you know `char` was 8 bits wide?

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am not allowed to us bitset for this project.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky Once I was horribly voted down for assuming POSIX-availability... Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't think of how to do this with the bitshift operators because you can't cast each bit into a char, but I know there must be a way to do it.

Look a bit more in to Bit shifting, perhaps? That's not an STL function. I bet your professor is trying to edge you towards low level bit operations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use bit shifting and masking.

```
void output_binary_rep(const std::string text&, std::ostream& output)
{
    // Look up CHAR_BIT, which contains the number of bits per character.
    const unsigned int length = text.length();

    // For each character in the string, do:
    for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < length; ++i)
    {
        // For each bit in the character, output a '1' or '0'.
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; ++j)
        {
             // Isolate a bit, from MSB to LSB, using
             // a 1 left shited by a number of bits.
             if (text[i] & (1 << (CHAR_BIT - j - 1)))
             {
                 output << "1";
             }
             else
             {
                 output << "0";
             }
        }
    }
}
```